# Make the child of a flex-child scroll on overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

**I was trying to make a child of a `flex-child` with `flex-grow=1` scroll when it overflows its parent.** However, instead of maintaining its size, the parent of the flex-child is growing to accommodate the size of the overflowing tag. **Is there a way to constrain the dimensions without explicitly setting the height/width of the ancestors (except the `<body>` tag)?**

*In the example blow*, the problematic `flex-child` would be the div with the `"ListParent"` class. I want it to always grow to take as much space as possible. However, if its children overflow the space available, it (or its children) should enable scrolling to show the content. So, the scrollable region would only be between the "Second Header" and "Footer" `divs`, not the entire html.

```css
.ConsumerParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.ConsumerLayer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #282c34;
  color: #fffffd;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.List {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.ListParent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.listItem {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-color: cyan !important;
  color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.Header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: "pink";
  border: 10px solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="ConsumerParent">
      <div>Other consumer comp</div>
      <div class="ConsumerLayer">
        <div>
          <div class="App">
            <div class="Header" style="background-color: red;">Hello World</div>
            <div class="Vertical">
              <div class="ListParent">
                <div>Second Header</div>
                <div class="List">
                  <div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #1</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #2</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #3</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #4</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #5</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #6</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #7</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #8</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #9</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #10</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #11</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #12</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #13</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #14</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #15</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #16</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #17</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #18</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #19</div>
                    <div class="listItem">Item #20</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>Footer</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in .ListParent  class try to fix the height - instead of percentage try with pixels

Comment: I want `ListParent` to take whatever space if available in `Vertical`; And `Vertical` to take up whatever space is left over from the `Header` in `App`. And `App` to be as big as its parent. So explicitly constraining the height won't work :(